# Can I open the OS native emoji picker in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are lots of javascript plugins and libraries to allow users to pick emojis for text inputs, but windows and mac already have native emoji pickers (<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>), Is there a way for me to open these native emoji pickers when a user clicks in a text field instead of installing plugins in my website?

I already tried emulate button key press, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: i dont think its possible.

Comment: Nope, you can't. AFAIK that's not possible because there's simply no standardized API for that. You probably has to open your own modal populated with your own selection of emojis.

Comment: I see, that's frustrating. Thank you, guys!

Comment: If we can get windows button and . buttons ascii values then it is possible but unfortunately we dont have windows button ascii value.

Comment: I don't think trying to open chromes emoji picker is a good idea since you will get in trouble with browser support

Comment: Something else you can try is to just loop through the emoji list and add everything to the page with a picker or something. It would require minimal JavaScript and would work just al well but without any platform dependency issues.

Comment: @Joeri, it's not chrome's emoji picker, it's the OS picker, so from Mac OS or Windows.

Comment: You're still going to have difficulties supporting systems like Linux and older versions of window and MacOS. On Ubuntu, 18.04 is the first version to even support emoji pickers out of the box. So I highly doubt it would be the easiest way...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short answer is no.

In order to access any OS feature from javascript, you need a corresponding browser API to support.

AFAIK, there isn't an API for that. There's a discussion [here](https://discourse.wicg.io/t/invoke-emoji-input/1030/13) which suggests adding `<input emoji />` to standard but seems no traction gained.

---

> **Edit**: Below is my original answer, revised. Comments pointed out I was focusing on the wrong aspect of the question, I totally agree.
>
> However, the OP obviously has some wrong idea about what you can do in javascript to leverage browser ability. So I think it's still worth clarification.

You can't send arbitrary emulated keyboard event from js and hoping the OS will respond. Were it possible, it'd be a severe security issue on browser's part. Imagine open a website and it fires a series of keyboard event to your OS and wipes out your desktop (totally feasible through shortcuts).

You need to understand the runtime env inside the browser is basically isolated from the one of native OS. Whatever OS feature that's accessible to your javascript is totally up for browser vendors to decide. For security reason, they are super careful in making these decisions.

Also, make a distinction on "what browser can do", and "what browser allows you to do in js". Seeing Chrome has an "Emoji & Symbols" context menu item, doesn't necessarily mean it decides to grant you the same ability in js.

To further clarify why the emulated keyboard event is fundamentally different from the native one, I include a graph here. The blue arrow is how emulated keyboard event flows. The farthest place it can reach is the browser's internal event bus. It never got a chance to reach the OS event bus, so no way to notify native emoji picker.
[image: keyboard event flow]

Comment: "it'd be a severe security issue on browser's part" only if you don't see "emoji picker" as a specialized keyboard. I mean, there is a way to instruct the browser to show a numeric keypad instead of a standard keyboard (`<input type="number">`), so I wouldn't assume there is an inherent security risk. It's just that such an input `type` doesn't exist.

Comment: ^ Agreed. The "you can't" conclusion may well be correct, but the reasoning is overboard. _There's simply no API for this_ would be sufficient; it *could* be done in a perfectly secure way.

Comment: Well, I agree, no API for that is the answer. I might be focusing on the wrong aspect. but OP seem have some very wrong idea on what you can do about script emulated event. Just wanna clarify on that.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think he meant it would be an issue to let JS code execute key commands, not to open the emoji keyboard.